# Creating a formula (syntax) in R for package

Tags: r

I have a likelihood function that enters as an argument in `maxLik` function of maxLik package. For example:

```
library(maxLik) 

likFun <- function(param, x, y, h) {

  dep   <- as.matrix(x[,y])
  indep <- as.matrix(x[,h])
  indep <- as.matrix(cbind(cons=1, indep))
  k     <- dim(indep)[2] 
  beta  <- as.matrix(param[1:k])
  xbeta <- crossprod(t(indep), beta)
  sig   <- param[k+1]
  res   <- (dep-xbeta)/sig
  sum(  (-(1/2)*log(2*pi)) - ((1/2)*log((sig)^2)) - ((res^2)/2)  )

}
model <- maxLik(likFun, start=c(0,0,0,1), grad=NULL, hess=NULL, x=mtcars, 
                y="mpg", h=c("cyl", "hp"))
summary(model)
```

Basically, the above likelihood function is using maximum likelihood for a multiple regression model. My question is how do I create a `formula` in R (for the package) like in `lm` so that the user would be able to enter the dependent variable and independent variables and data. I have checked `model.matrix` but I am not sure whether it is the one I should be looking for. Any suggestion in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear to me.  Your function seems to take as its arguments the independent and dependent variables.  Where does the need for a `formula` take place?

Comment: @ Carl:  I am trying to develop this (not exactly this) in the form of package. So, I can't use this version.

Comment: Would you like to use something like `mpg ~ cyl + hp` instead of `y="mpg", h=c("cyl", "hp")` in the arguments?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to call your function using something like `mpg ~ cyl + hp` instead of `y="mpg", h=c("cyl", "hp")` in the arguments, you can use a formula object. They are unevaluated by default, so you don't need `substitute` nor `match.call`.

If you want something more complex than simply stripping out the symbols in each side of the formula, you'll have to write your own parser. Otherwise, use function `all.vars`:

```
f <- function(data, formula){
    print("Right hand side:")
    print(head(data[,all.vars(formula[[3]]), drop=FALSE]))
    print("Left hand side:")
    print(head(data[,all.vars(formula[[2]]), drop=FALSE]))
}
```

Result:

```
> f(mtcars, mpg ~ cyl + hp)
[1] "Right hand side:"
                  cyl  hp
Mazda RX4           6 110
Mazda RX4 Wag       6 110
Datsun 710          4  93
Hornet 4 Drive      6 110
Hornet Sportabout   8 175
Valiant             6 105
[1] "Left hand side:"
                   mpg
Mazda RX4         21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0
Datsun 710        22.8
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4
Hornet Sportabout 18.7
Valiant           18.1
```

Comment: Yep; my go-to answer to questions like this is, roughly, "Read the source code for the referenced item"  In this case, for `lm`

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, you use `eval` inside the function. However, you first need to get your function arguments in an unevaluated context (so that you can substitute the variables into the formula). To do this, you’d need `match.call`. Here’s a very basic example:

```
f <- function (.FUN, ...) {
    args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    eval(args$.FUN, args$...)
}
```

This will capture the formula in `.FUN` and the actual arguments in `...`, which can be accessed (as a list) via `args$...`.

Now you can call that function similar to `lm`:

```
> f(x + y, x = 1, y = 2)
3
```

As an alternative to `match.call`, you could also use `substitute` to get a function argument in an unevaluated context:

```
f <- function (.FUN, ...)
    eval(substitute(.FUN), list(...))
```